# UITableView with custom UITableViewCell not displaying cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, custom-cell

`UITableView` with **custom** `UITableViewCell` not displaying cell separator while not scrolling. At time of scrolling it displaying separator. I have set cell separator `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine` still not displaying. I am checking in simulator. iOS version is 9.3.

Help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Check on different Simulators and on an actual device too. Maybe it's a simulator related issue.

Comment: check on device it will display!

Comment: Any reason for down vote the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is not an issue with code. Apple now provide a scaled simulators so you can check the device output 5 different scaled simulator that you change by following. And you also can check the real Device your divider must be appear but for the simulator you need to just change the simulator scale 100% like following.

[image]

Comment: thanks minus voter i think i wrote something wrong in my answer. so i wanted to know what's my mistake if you have reason then come and show me.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are not able to see divider because having scaling issue so it will be appears on device and increase the scale so u will able to see .

Comment: congratulation  :)